# java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException

Tags: java

I am having a little problem in my code here. I have no idea how I am supposed to fix it, and I tried some stuff, but I think, I'm not getting the message here, even though I suspect the issue to be some kind of elemental and easy to fix problem. The exceptions are below the code.

```
package test;
public class CircleExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] rKreis = new double[3];

        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++){

            rKreis[i] = Double.parseDouble("4.9");

            System.out.printf("%n%d, Kreis: %nRadius: %d%nUmfang: %d%nFlaeche: %d%n",
                    i, rKreis[i], Circle.getCircumference(rKreis[i]), Circle.getArea(rKreis[i]));   
        }
    }
}
```

Exception is as follows

```
1, Kreis: 
Radius: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:3999)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2709)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2661)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2433)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821)
    at CircleExercise.main(CircleExercise.java:13)
```

Comment: The exception tells you right here that you need to something other than `%d`: " `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double`"

Answer (score 40):

`%d` goes with integer in Java. Use `%f` instead in your `printf()`

Another useful info. If you use `%.02f` then it will print only two decimal point value after the dot `.`

Comment: It somehow didn't work the way you suggested. I just changed to normal "System.out.println". Thank you anyways.

Comment: This is how I am doing the formatting as @sabuj suggested and it's working.`Double myTestScore = new Double(1000000); String myFormattedString = String.format("%,.0f", myTestScore);
        System.out.println(myFormattedString);`

Comment: for double its also f?

Comment: 'f' for floating point - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax
This will work for doubles (simulated with Kreis as 4th and 5ft parameters to bypass unsuplied Circle class):
System.out.printf("%n%d, Kreis: %nRadius: %f%nUmfang: %f%nFlaeche: %f%n",
                    i, rKreis[i], rKreis[i], rKreis[i]);

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and solve like this

```
 if (allRec.get(i).getType() == 2) {
                        totalExpense = totalExpense.add(new BigDecimal**(String.format("%.2f",allRec.get(i).getAmount()))**);
                        tvExpense.setText("-" + moneySym + totalExpense + "");
                    }

  if (allRec.get(i).getType() == 1) {
                        // it throws number format exception
                        totalIncome = totalIncome.add(new **BigDecimal(String.format("%.2f",(allRec.get(i).getAmount()))));**
                        tvIncome.setText(moneySym + totalIncome + "");
                    }
```

[image: String format table]